# How to access sqlite database from another page javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova

In phonegap cordova, everything happens after "deviceready".  The database opens and then names of players are inserted into the database. I have successfully displayed those players' names inside buttons on this html page -- a function getRecords which calls fun resultSuccess, but when I try to call that function from another page it runs the whole script from beginning and then throws an error.

`function errorcb() { alert("Can't add player into DataBase!"); db.close();`

```js
window.onload = function() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", OnDeviceReady, false);
  document.getElementById("submitbtn").addEventListener("click", getplayers, false);
  document.getElementById("subb").addEventListener("click", getRecords, false);

  document.getElementById("btn0").addEventListener("click", deletePlayer, false); // DELETE PLAYER
  document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", deletePlayer, false); // DELETE PLAYER
  document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", deletePlayer, false); // DELETE PLAYER
  document.getElementById("btn3").addEventListener("click", deletePlayer, false); // DELETE PLAYER
  document.getElementById("btn4").addEventListener("click", deletePlayer, false); // DELETE PLAYER
  document.getElementById("btn5").addEventListener("click", deletePlayer, false); // DELETE PLAYER
  document.getElementById("btn6").addEventListener("click", deletePlayer, false); // DELETE PLAYER
  document.getElementById("btn7").addEventListener("click", deletePlayer, false); // DELETE PLAYER

}

var db, clickable = true;
var pname1, pname2, pname3, pname4, pname5, pname6, pname7, pname8;
var idDelete;

function OnDeviceReady() {
  alert("device is ready!");
  makeDB();
  clickable = true;
}

function openDB() {
  return window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
    name: 'playerDB.db',
    location: 'default'
  });
}

function makeDB() {
  db = openDB();
  db.transaction(fillDB, errorcb, successcb);

  alert("User: makeDB");

}

function fillDB(tx) {
  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name text)');
}

function successcb() {
  alert("TABLE created Successfully!");
}

function errorcb() {
  alert("Can't add player into DataBase!");
  db.close();
}

function defaultsuccess() {
  alert("default success");
}

function defaultfault(error) {
  alert("default pogreska: " + error);
}

function transactionsucces() {
  alert("Transaction success");
}

function transactionfault() {
  alert("Transaction fault");
}

function otvoristr() { // funckija otvara wheel.html 

  window.location.assign("wheel.html"); //works on android
}

function getRecords() {
  db = openDB();
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    //alert("getRecords");
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM player", [], resultSuccess, resultError);
  }, transactionfault, transactionsucces);
}

function resultSuccess(tx, response) {
  alert("Response : " + response);
  var div = document.getElementById("divResponse");
  var temp = "<table><tr><th>name</th></tr></table>";

  alert(response.rows.length); //4

  for (var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) { //append all strings
    $(div).append(temp += '<button id="btn' + i + '" onClick="tellId(this.id)">' + response.rows.item(i).name + '</button>');
    //temp += "<button>" + response.rows.item(i).name+"</button>";
    alert(response.rows.item(i).id);
  }
  div.innerHTML = temp;
}

function tellId(clicked_id) {
  alert(clicked_id);
}

function resultError(error) {
  alert("greska e: " + error.message);
}

function getplayers() {
    if (!clickable) return;
    alert("insert into table p1 p2");

    //getting id of fields and insert into table-database

  }
  //opens page wheel.html
otvoristr();
}
/*+++++++++++++++++++++               DELETE              ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
function deletePlayer() {
  //delete function
}

function deleteSuccess() {
  alert('DELETE error: ' + error.message);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
  <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/640i.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slidingview.css" />

  <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.animate-enhanced.js"></script>
  <script src="js/slidingview.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="../plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js"></script> - not working-->
  <script src="SQLitePlugin.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      //Setup the ViewNavigator
      new SlidingView('sidebar', 'body');
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/media.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slidingview_wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <div class="logoinfo">
        <img id="headerlogo" src="icon.png" />
      </div>
      <nav>
        <a href="wheel.html">
          <p class="sideP">app</p>
        </a>
        <a href="info.html">
          <p class="sideP">Info</p>
        </a>
        <div id="deviceready">
          <a href="#" onclick="app.alert()">
            <p class="sideP">Version</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
      <small id="indextext">SLIDE</small>

      <header>
        <!--
                    <div class="ilogo">
                        <img id="headerlogo" src="icon.png"/><br/>
                    </div>
                    -->
      </header>
      <table id="tablica1">
        <tr id="tr1">
          <th>Player 1:</th>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="playersname1" name="playerName" value="hani" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr2">
          <th>Player 2:</th>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="playersname2" name="playerName" value="hanuska" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr3">
          <th>Player 3:</th>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="playersname3" name="playerName" value="ivan" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr4">
          <th>Player 4:</th>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="playersname4" name="playerName" value="nikolina" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr5">
          <th>Player 5:</th>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="playersname5" name="playerName" value="" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr6">
          <th>Player 6:</th>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="playersname6" name="playerName" value="" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr7">
          <th>Player 7:</th>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="playersname7" name="playerName" value="" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr8">
          <th>Player 8:</th>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="playersname8" name="playerName" value="" />
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="tr9">
          <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Play" id="submitbtn">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!--<a href="pdata.html">Open pdata</a>-->
      <!--This instructs the Cordova CLI to inject a platform specific 
version of cordova.js at build time. In other words, cordova.js doesn't 
need to be (and shouldn't be) present in your project/www folder.-->

      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/basesql.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: are your variables and functions available on the other page?

Comment: I include that basesql.js file on other page so they should be available

Comment: I'm not sure it matters in this case, but the Phone Gap API docs suggest that you attach the deviceready event listener INSIDE of the window.onload function.  That means you'd swap your first two lines of script above.  I guess the way you have it, the device ready event could fire before the javascript is all loaded.  So it's probably worth doing anyhow.  I would guess there is an off chance that it might fix your issue also :-)

Comment: Also change your alerts to console.log.  That's always important if you may be dealing with a timing issue.

Comment: @spozun i swap lines, thx for that :), but still when new page opens he runs script from begining and it calls device ready function, i put button on the page which should call getRecords function but nothing happend.. also working with alert becasue i run it on android phone

Comment: changed alert with navigator.notification.alert to be more native

Comment: What is the error though? That the user already exists? Or it can't connect to the database? Or something else? Can you get the actual error that comes out of the database call?

Comment: hey there :), so i make the db, insert name of the players and list them on same page-- works, so when i try list them on another page from the same db i get the error when the page loads--> alert("Can't add player into DataBase!") from the code -->function makeDB-->errorcb. cant check are players written in db or db is refreshed and all players are set to null